# Infer parameters from return type of generic

Tags: typescript

I'm creating a function whereby the first parameter is an array of "services", and the second parameter infers the return type of those services. For example:

```
const serviceOne = createService([], () => Promise.resolve({} as Service1));
const serviceTwo = createService([], () => Promise.resolve({} as Service2));

const serviceThree = createService(
  [serviceOne, serviceTwo],
  (one, two) => Promise.resolve({}), // one should be inferred as Service1, two should be inferred as Service2
);
```

How can I modify my function signature to achieve this inference? At the moment, I have them typed as `any`

```
function createService<T extends Service<any>[], U>(deps: T, factory: (...args: any[]) => Promise<U>) {
  return {} as Service<U>;
}

type Service<U> = {
  instance: U
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmAnAbgS2PA8meMC8Mwi8AhlPAMpJoYAUA2gLoA0MtAlPgHwwAKiIALaoEAOmIQQAG2TxaAbwC%20MEhBhUU6eAEZ27ANwBYAFAnQkWAk0YAKgHcQ%20QsTKVqWhizac8PfkJF4cXhJGTklFTUNGngAJj0jU2NzaDh3WwALYlwCIlJyaI8TGBh6KxjseFZyrXsQFmK2cCqYKAcfPwFhMQlpWQVlVXV0%20ABmdlYAekmYZrgMkABXKQATGAAjXFQwADMkYjWhwoxtVjbHCAXltc2Ybb3EA8jh6ziTAxMTHcWwYChUcDOfJuV4AHhsMHgAA9yGAVlERkwuLQVvAAA4QABcMBsrB2JD%20IEQAE9sbRRBSSIgAOZYlRgYlMDp8LqBUEkBlcTjyRrEKCLRBgGARI4jRKKT7GKDEtG4Y45YWKRImaWyl4xbROHnGEqSQTwABCIGk2PWxqkpDAJglSVVcpGsS1jT1lCgiGx0EQ22p4sldvVWlGTp1cCE8AAcotBNiwFHNohxUA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first need to change the constraint to `T` to get typescript to infer a tuple type instead of an array type. To do this, we just need to add a union with the empty tuple to the constraint (`[] |`). This will set typescript in the right state to infer tuples

We can then  use a mapped type to map from a tuple containing `Service<any>` to a tuple containing the service types:

```
const serviceThree = createService(
  [serviceOne, serviceTwo],
  (one, two) => Promise.resolve({} as Service3), // one is Service1, two is Service2
);

type GetServiceType<T extends Service<any>[]> = unknown [] & {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Service<infer R> ? R: never
}
function createService<T extends [] | Service<any>[], U>(deps: T, factory: (...args: any[] & GetServiceType<T>) => Promise<U>) {
  return {} as Service<U>;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmAnAbgS2PA8meMC8Mwi8AhlPAMpJoYAUA2gLoA0MtAlPgHwwAKiIALaoEAOmIQQAG2TxaAbwC+MEhBhUU6eAEZ27ANwBYAFAnQkWAk0YAKgHcQ+QsTKVqWhizac8PfkJF4cXhJGTklFTUNGngAJj0jU2NzaDh3WwALYlwCIlJyaI8TGBh6KxjseFZyrXsQFmK2cCqYKAcfPwFhMQlpWQVlVXV0+ABmdlYAekmYZpgRYesdVjbHBcKMWJMDExMoAE8AB1wAcXgoDfgbI-gAHhsYeAAPcjAAEyiR25Iwfa4mHgEACuYAA1mAQHYwKVGDAAGQweSNei8ebQ0HwfYgABmMBsjAAXHiUbDnq8PosYrdUGBsUgYAAlHgAfkZRJwskQJkUJmxIOAUFQ4Gc+TcS3ujxe8HeaiYMAAPpStN9fv8vABVLi0N7wQ4QIk2VjYkgCkCIfZE2iia0kRAAc31Kl+coRZwuI2ux3uXA6fC6gVums4SOMJWIUCBiGhESGl0DXESPKSB2OSow8acIZKNOgPwwRPV3MSexuaZ0mcakkE8AAQiBpESAEb1qSkMDc3bGFO4S6xCuhuBCShQRBE6CIGl2xOd7tl0b9kpV+AAOSBgnZa8bSETQA)